# flask - how to work with routes

Tags: python, angularjs, flask

I am using flask with angular.  I dont dont know why this does not work.  I guess flask routes.

This works.  I get my chart

```
localhost:5000/flotcandle
```

This does not work.  I get a blank page but get I see the html source code

```
localhost:5000/ssl/flotcandle
```

In flask all I change is this

```
@app.route('/flotcandle')
def flotcandle():
    return make_response(open('/home/ubuntu/workspace/forex-api/app/templates/flotcandle.html').read())
```

TO the blow with /ssl added

```
@app.route('/ssl/flotcandle')
def flotcandle():
    return make_response(open('/home/ubuntu/workspace/forex-api/app/templates/flotcandle.html').read())
```

Here is my angular code.  I cant see why anythin would change here

```
var App = angular.module('App', []);
"use strict";

App.controller('Ctrl', function ($scope,$http) {

    var data = {"observed": [[0, 1.67122], [1, 1.67121], [2, 1.67153], [3, 1.67153], [4, 1.67043], [5, 1.6713], [6, 1.67043], [7, 1.67043], [8, 1.66995], [9, 1.66991], [10, 1.67011], [11, 1.67011], [12, 1.66995], [13, 1.66998], [14, 1.66998], [15, 1.67023], [16, 1.67003], [17, 1.67023], [18, 1.67023], [19, 1.67037]], "date": [[0, "2014-04-14 08:05:00"], [1, "2014-04-14 08:10:00"], [2, "2014-04-14 08:10:00"], [3, "2014-04-14 08:15:00"], [4, "2014-04-14 08:15:00"], [5, "2014-04-14 08:20:00"], [6, "2014-04-14 08:20:00"], [7, "2014-04-14 08:25:00"], [8, "2014-04-14 08:30:00"], [9, "2014-04-14 08:30:00"], [10, "2014-04-14 08:30:00"], [11, "2014-04-14 08:35:00"], [12, "2014-04-14 08:40:00"], [13, "2014-04-14 08:40:00"], [14, "2014-04-14 08:45:00"], [15, "2014-04-14 08:45:00"], [16, "2014-04-14 08:50:00"], [17, "2014-04-14 08:50:00"], [18, "2014-04-14 08:55:00"], [19, "2014-04-14 09:00:00"]], "forecast": [[0, 1.67052], [1, 1.67123], [2, 1.67123], [3, 1.67093], [4, 1.67093], [5, 1.67149], [6, 1.67149], [7, 1.67135], [8, 1.6715], [9, 1.6715], [10, 1.6715], [11, 1.66981], [12, 1.67011], [13, 1.67011], [14, 1.67007], [15, 1.67007], [16, 1.66988], [17, 1.66988], [18, 1.67009], [19, 1.67026]]};

    var data1 = data.observed;
    var data2 = data.forecast; 
    var data = [{data:data1,label: 'observed'},
                {data:data2,label: 'forecast',lines:{show:true},points:{show:true}}
               ];
    $scope.data = data;

});

App.directive('chart', function() {
  return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {data: '='},
            link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
              scope.$watch('data', function() {
                if (scope.data.length > 0) {
                  var options = {
                      legend: { show: true},
                      lines:{show:true},
                      points:{show:true},
                      grid: {backgroundColor: '#ffffff'}
                  };
                  $.plot(elem, scope.data, options);
                  elem.show();
                }
              });
            }
          };//End return
});//End App
```

Here is my html..,again..cant see why anything would change here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/jquery/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/flot/jquery.flot.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="static/lib/flot/controller.js"></script>
    <style type='text/css'>
       chart {
            display:none;
            width:800px;
            height:400px;
        }
   </style>
 </head>
 <body>
    <div ng-app='App'>
        <div ng-controller='Ctrl'>
            <chart data='data'></chart>
        </div>
    </div>    
  </body>
</html>
```

so..all I did was change `@app.route('/flotcandle')` to `@app.route('/ssl/flotcandle')`

Comment: What does the debug output look like when you're getting from `'/ssl/flotcandle'`? I cannot reproduce this with a flask only test..

Comment: Did you restart your app after you changed the route?

Comment: Solved.  is was the source in the html.  I had to change from static to ../static.  Thanks